# How to update Manjaro to the latest version available?

Tags: upgrade, manjaro, version, software-updates

I recently started using Linux, and Manjaro seemed to be the best 64-bit option available at the time for my new Raspberry Pi 4. I'm using the KDE Plasma version, and loving every bit of it. I have one issue though.

From time to time, the notification center alerts me of things like

- [[ARM Stable Update] 2020-08-25](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/arm-stable-update-2020-08-25-libreoffice-gcc-pamac-kde-applications-and-kernels/14432)
- [Manjaro ARM 20.08 released!](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/manjaro-arm-20-08-released/1516)

I have been using both `pacman` and `pamac` to update individual programs, but there doesn't seem to be an option to update to the next OS version. If I wanted to have the latest Manjaro release, how do I update Manjaro to the latest version? Or perhaps, even downgrade to a previous version?

Can this be done through package managers? Or do I need to install the latest image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manjaro is a rolling-release distribution. This means as long as you continue to periodically update, you'll be on the latest version of Manjaro. That's done by running:

```
pacman -Syu
```

[Manjaro unstable](https://manjaro.org/features/fresh-and-stable/) is about a day behind Arch.  After a package has been in Manjaro for a couple of weeks without issue (fast-tracked for security fixes), it is put into the stable distribution which is probably what you are using.

The "releases" are a bit confusing.  They are actually more of a snapshot.  [Manjaro's wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/The_Rolling_Release_Development_Model) says:

> It would seem that some confusion has arisen due to the regular (and somewhat rapid) occurrence of new Manjaro releases. This confusion has been compounded still further by the use of version numbers (for example: 18.0.2,18.1 and so on), a custom normally associated with the Standard Release Development Model, where a brand-new release of an operating system must be re-installed over an old version in order to access any new features provided. These releases are more accurately new snapshots of the Manjaro system. Just like photographs, these snapshots are in essence images that portray the Manjaro system at a particular point in its development. As such, one purpose they serve is to help the developers to both chart and evaluate the continued development of the Manjaro system, as it is of course easier to pick up on the finer details from a single image than from a moving picture.
>
> Since Manjaro is constantly rolling forward, a snapshot of the Manjaro system will very quickly become out of date. New snapshots are therefore released in order to make life easier for new users, who may otherwise be faced with the prospect of downloading huge volumes of new software packages to update and upgrade their newly installed systems from an older ISO.